# writing xml to mysql table

Tags: mysql, xml, insert, foreach

I have an XML file I am using, and I need to get this into my database. I am going to use cronjob to update this hourly as content changes often.

I have a for each statement in PHP which I was using to output the XML, but I am just wondering on what the best way is to do this? I obviously need to do both update and insert depending on if its new data or not.

XML

```
<G DBID="31878623" EID="2458701" N="3Way - result" GT="17">
<R DBID="110281497" N="1" O="1.57"/>
<R DBID="110281498" N="X" O="3.50"/>
<R DBID="110281499" N="2" O="6.25"/>
</G>
```

Can someone give me some ideas on the best way to do this. My foreach code only returns 1 row in the XML and I need all of them, so I am a little stuck, and also I am unsure on how to do both update and insert in mysql.

Thanks in advance

Richard

Answer (score 0):

You can import data from the XML file with a [LOAD XML](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html) statement.If you want to insert or replace depending on key information then you could use REPLACE keyword.

Also, try [Data Import](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html) tool in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (XML format, Append/Update mode).